# Is there software that blocks all porn sites?

Tags: parental-control, content-filtering

I have tried multiple software to block porn sites, e.g. Sophos Home and Microsoft Family Safety. However, each time it is still possible to access porn quite easily. Is there software that blocks all porn sites or at least makes it very hard to find porn which is not blocked?

Comment: Note that at least in France, some internet providers can, on demand, provide such a software.   It is likely to exist in many countries.

Comment: @Damien, could you give a source for those providers in France?

Comment: Orange for example. The so-called *Contrôle Parental*.

Comment: @Damien, is this particular software better than other porn block software like, for example, Net Nanny?

Comment: Sorry, I did not test them. I made some research, found that Orange solution is based on *Optenet Web Filter*. Note that this software is not restricted to blocking of porn sites. Due to notoriety of Orange (at least in France), I would be very surprised that it is not efficient. The main issue is that Orange software is likely to be restricted to Orange customers. You may ask to your own internet provider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First there is nothing thats going to block all porn.  New sites are popping every minute.  But I have found these two approaches worked for my kids.  I was using both, but you can use either.

1. **OpenDNS** -  The basic account is free.  It comes with categories so you can tick porn, gambling etc.  You run a small program on your "PC" that updates your ip address at their site.  And you have to make it your DNS on your router.
2. **Pi Hole** - It runs on a "raspberry pi" and is a DNS, not a proxy, so it doesn't impact speed.  It is meant for cutting out ads.  I found it easier to add the sites that were missed by OPENDNS.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest [Safes Family](https://www.safes.so/family) from Safes.so.

It has English and German only, but it works in other places too. I found out when we were travelling. it's a pretty good monitoring and controlling app.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It would help your answer if you expanded it with more details.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to block porn on Android is [here](https://cleanbrowsing.org/guides/android/) and you can ask someone close to you to set a password for the cleanbrowsing app...

There are options for Windows and Linux too.

Comment: Welcome! This answer is what our community calls a "link only" answer.  Instead of just providing a link, please provide details so your answer is self-contained.  Thanks, and again, welcome!

Comment: Since the OP did not specify Android, your answer would be more complete if you added options for Windows and Linux too.